# Transistor: Mix both GND

Tags: transistors

I Googled a little bit about transistors and I figured out I have a general understanding problem. Can I simply connect the emitter of the transistor to the GND of my microcontroller that controls the transistor but also to the GND of the 12V I try to control with the transistor, to close both circuits?

Would the circuit shown below work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjVaVH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit you show in your scheme will not work. Chances are that the transistor is damaged. For a transistor connected as a switch, it is normal to place the load in the collector circuit, as I show below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEUrxo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the basic way to connect a NPN transistor in the output of a microcontroller to activate a load.

When the output pin is in high, the transistor will conduct, feeding the load, in this case an LED. The value of the base resistance depends on the supply voltage of the microcontroller and the maximum current that support. The value of the collector resistor depends on the source Vcc, and the load that would like to activate.

This way, you can share the GND connection between the microcontroller and the power supply to the load.

Comment: So first of all i can simply share the two GNDs, but i should place the load "before" the collector (why ?) !?

The resistor Rb you added is just there to limit the Micro controller current to the max current the Transistor Base ?can handle ?

Comment: @user2021331 Yes you can share GND. Think about the transistor like a switch; when the output of microcontroller is high, the switch (trnsistor) is closed, then the load circuit (LED) is active. Check the current path from the source Vcc through R1, LED, switch (transistor) and finally reach GND. Why LED on collector? because the source voltage of the load circuit maybe (sure) is not the same as the source of microcontroller, e.g. the source for the load can be 12V, but for the uC can be 5V. But the GND has the same level for all.

Comment: With the load between emitter and ground, the transistor is acting as an emitter follower - the emitter voltage will always be about 0.7 volts below the base voltage., regardless of the collector voltage.  With the load between the collector and a positive supply, and the emitter grounded, the transistor will act as a switch and will only have about 0.2 volts between emitter and collector, leaving almost the whole supply voltage across the load (and the supply voltage for the load can be different than the supply voltage for the microcontroller).

Comment: @user2021331 The resistor Rb is here to limit the current from the uC, not for the transistor base.  When the transistor switches on, the base-emitter voltage is approximately 0.7 V. The only current limitation is provided by the Rb resistance. This current comes from the microcontroller output transistor, so if it is not limited to Rb may damage the microcontroller.